# Do Ultra or Master Balls exist in Pokémon GO?

Tags: pokemon-go

Are there Ultra Balls or Master Balls in Pokémon GO? So far I've only seen the normal PokéBall and Great Ball.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You will get ultra balls as your trainer level increases. Specifically, [ultra balls start showing up at pokestops once you hit level 20](http://www.gopedia.net/index.php?title=Pokeball).

[Master balls exist in the game's code](https://np.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4s3wog/pok%C3%A9mon_go_new_discoveries_mew_mewtwo_masterballs/), but have not been seen in game yet. Most likely Niantic will unveil them as they add features and levels in the future.

Comment: "Master balls are at level 30" Reference please? As far as I know you don't get *any* master balls, even at level 40.

Comment: @GodEmperorDune so weird because at level 40 you get hyper balls which is a lower tier than master ball

Comment: @Kiwi the [level 40 screenshot that shows a hyperball reward](https://np.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4us5d9/i_just_hit_level_40_world_first/) is actually an ultraball in a different language. [Silph road has it as an ultraball](https://thesilphroad.com/research#trainerLevels)

Comment: @Rakete1111 the master ball info was incorrect, i've adjusted my answer accordingly.

Comment: @GodEmperorDune ah true indeed sorry

Answer (score 9):

At level 12 a player unlocks Great Balls and at level 20 a player will unlock Ultra Balls. At the point of unlocking them a player will also be able to receive them from Poke Stops.

The Master Ball was indeed found in the code but it is not available to the public (yet).

A list of all level up rewards can be found [here](http://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-go/Level_Rewards_and_Unlockable_Items).